# what is the name of theme in android studio, which is shown in presentations?

Tags: android

what is the theme name, used in android official presentations?, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksgEM.png)

is there any theme list, that i can try to find the corresponding theme?
i have tried all the default themes in File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts but nothing helped